# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-

Tags: exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2630)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)`

Answer (score 26):

```
 sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Seems you have only headless package installed (`openjdk-11-headless`).

Answer (score 0):

1- First of all install openjdk 11, if you didn't yet, using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

2- Add Java-home path to your environment vars, using this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

then Add the path where your openjdk-11 got installed(exple):

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

3- Reload your env file, using:

```
source /etc/environment
```

4- Check if your environment variable has been set correctly, using:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

it should return your path(exple):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```